# PHP Javascript Image rendering

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have two forms in two different divs and in one of which I am trying to render the images from a folder:

First form renders a `ul li` and its id and name is `matchListUL`.

```
 echo '<li id="matchList" name="matchList"><a href="'.implode('; ', $data).'">'.implode('; ', $data).'</a></li>';
```

Through a javascript I am passing the value of selected li to a php file named loadimages.php. The following is the javascript.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul#matchListUL li a').click(function(){
      var match = $(this).attr('href');
      if (match !== null && match !=="") {
      $.post("loadimages.php", { match : match }, function(output){
      $("#imageload").html(output).show();
      });
          return false;
           })
      })
</script>
```

The second div has id and name as imageload.  The loadimages.php is as follows:

```
$match = $_POST['match'];
$selectedDir = $_SESSION['seldir'];
$tarDir = "kennels/" . $selectedDir . "/" . $match;

$my_image_array = scandir($tarDir);                    
$img_string = "";
foreach($my_image_array as $img_name){
    if(strlen($img_name) > 2 ) {
        $imgname = $tarDir . $img_name;    
        $img_string .= '<img src = "' .$imgname. '">';
    }
}
echo $img_string;
```

When I run the code from loadimages.php, the images are not getting rendered.  Do I have to change this line in my javascript to suit image rendering?

```
$("#imageload").html(output).show();
```

The same code when I run (with minimal modifications) from my main index.php, it renders images.

I tried an alternative to the code i have in loadimages.php where I hardcoded the path to the images folder:

```
$files = glob("kennels/projects/images/*.jpg");
for ($i=1; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
    $num = $files[$i];
    echo '<img src="'.$num.'" id="thumbNails"/>';

}
```

This too works perfectly from my index.php, while not rendering any images from loadimages.php.

Comment: If you are using mvc or another folder you may want to specify the part your kennels using /kennels/img/path assuming the kennels folder is in your main host directory that is the / path

Comment: Can you is the index.php in the same path as your loadimages.php?

Comment: @Ezekiel Yes, the kennels directory is in my main host directory, and yes, index.php and loadimages.php are in the same path.  In fact, I do not have any directories yet for any of my files.  All of them are in the host only except for images.

Comment: @Ezekiel Do you see any other anomalies in the code as I have it now?

Comment: Yes, i think i may have seen, $imagename = $tarDir.'/'.$img_name; should be the right thing. Once you make changes let me know so i can leave it as an answer for others also

Comment: @Ezekiel Still no response.  When I try to echo / print_r each level, I am seeing my `$my_image_array` is not printing. Can I not pass a array to javascript? I am sorry if this is too basic..but when I print the array from index.php it prints.

Comment: lets first sort out the issue at hand before you start trying to pass an array to javascript which is not possible only if passed using json_encode to convert it into Json format and translate it into javascript object or array in the front end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice there is no .'/' after your $match variable

```
 $match = $_POST['match'];
$selectedDir = $_SESSION['seldir'];
$tarDir= "kennels/" . $selectedDir . "/" . $match;
```

So when you run it through a loop

```
$my_image_array = scandir($tarDir);                    
 $img_string = "";
 foreach($my_image_array as $img_name){
if(strlen($img_name) > 2 ) {
    $imgname = $tarDir . $img_name;    
    $img_string .= '<img src = "' .$imgname. '">';
   }
}
echo $img_string;
```

It will echo something like this "kennels/imagesImagefile.ext" instead of
"kennels/images/Imagefile.ext"

So to solve this you either add the slash / after the $match variable or in between $tarDir and $img_name like this

```
 $imgname = $tarDir.'/'. $img_name;
```

Also in your jQuery post request
Add to it a qoute to your first match

```
$.post("loadimages.php", { 'match' : match }, 
function(output)
```

Comment: Yes I got the same.  But as I said, it is not working.

Comment: Try qouting the first match in your jQuery $.post("loadimages.php", { 'match' : match }, function(output)

Comment: Thank you so much....the quotes around the match did work.  Thanks a ton.  If you can rephrase your answer, I will accept it.  Thank you so much again.  Been breaking my head for the entire day today.

Comment: I will rephrase by adding to it